# Please explain me behaviour of C#. Object from reference

Tags: c#, object, reference

I have method with one argument which is instance of my created class - Chessfield which contain three tables - one of integers and two of bools.

In the method I have also List of Chessfield which is the return object of my method.

I am modifying chessfield (so the object from reference) and add it on list List.Add(Chessfield) several times (one time after each change).

In the end return object (so list contain several object of Chessfield) all instances are the same unrespecting my changes !

I have read similar topic and try to put 'ref' before argument and the place where I proceed this method. 
Without success also I tried to create instance of Chessfield inside the method and assign to it Chessfield object from reference, then making changes on internal created object.

How I can solve it ? In the end I need to receive list of objects which each is a little bit modified from original one (from reference).

Have a nice day !!

p.s. If the code will be helpful then I cut and paste general idea code.

EDIT:

Joel undrestand me Good ! The difference is that inside object are tables and it makes the problem more complex, because I do few changes in these tables in compare to this original object. To be more clear I paste my code:

```
public class Chessfield
{

    public int[] pieces = new int[64];
    public bool[] blacks = new bool[64];
    public bool[] whites = new bool[64];

    public Chessfield(int[] pieces, bool[] blacks, bool[] whites)
    {
        this.pieces = pieces;
        this.blacks = blacks;
        this.whites = whites;
    }

    public Chessfield()
    {

    }

}
```

And method look like this:

```
    static public List<Chessfield> MakeAllMovesForWhites(Chessfield chessfieldModel)
    {
        List<Chessfield> listOfPossibleMoves = new List<Chessfield>(); // list containing chessfields with changed position of figures
        int indexOfCurrentPosition = 0; //start with field 0 (most top left)

        foreach (bool singleEnemyChecker in chessfieldModel.whites) //iterate all fields,  table of whites contain information if white field stand on the field (true, otherwise false), 
        {
            if (singleEnemyChecker == true) //so algorithm will proceed only fields with white figure
            {
                int kindOfPiece = chessfieldModel.pieces[indexOfCurrentPosition]; // (table pieces contain information which kind of figure stand on particular field 0 -> empty, 1 -> soldier, 2-> tower, 3 -> horse etc...
                switch (kindOfPiece)// (based on figure at field it is going to predict all possible moves
                {

                    case 2: // tower case
                        if (indexOfCurrentPosition % 8 != 0) // check if the field is not most left, otherwise leave 
                        {
                            int localIndexIterator = indexOfCurrentPosition; //localIndex iterate all possible moves in left direction
                            while (localIndexIterator % 8 != 0) // checking if tower is standing on the most left field
                            {
                                localIndexIterator = localIndexIterator - 1; //iterate all possible moves of tower for left direction
                                if (chessfieldModel.pieces[localIndexIterator] == 0) //if there are no figures on checking field proceed:
                                {
                                    chessfieldModel.pieces[indexOfCurrentPosition] = 0; // erase tower from original position
                                    chessfieldModel.whites[indexOfCurrentPosition] = false; // and mark that white tower is not standing there anymore
                                    chessfieldModel.pieces[localIndexIterator] = 2; // put tower on new place
                                    chessfieldModel.whites[localIndexIterator] = true; // and mark that on new place there is white figure

                                    listOfPossibleMoves.Add(chessfieldModel); // here I add changed object of chessfield to list

                                    chessfieldModel.pieces[indexOfCurrentPosition] = 2; // here I come back to original chessfield
                                    chessfieldModel.whites[indexOfCurrentPosition] = true;
                                    chessfieldModel.pieces[localIndexIterator] = 0;
                                    chessfieldModel.whites[localIndexIterator] = false;
                                }
                                else //if there is figure at checking field
                                    break; //leave this case
                            }
                        }
                        if (indexOfCurrentPosition % 8 != 7) // right direction case
                        {
                          // here is similar code to the sample above
                        }
                        if (indexOfCurrentPosition / 8 != 0) //top direction case
                        {
                          // here is similar code to the sample above
                        }
                        if (indexOfCurrentPosition / 8 != 7) //bottom direction case
                        {
                          // here is similar code to the sample above
                        }
                        break;

       // here are another figures horse and so on...

                }
            }
            indexOfCurrentPosition++; // go to next field...
        }

        return listOfPossibleMoves; //return list of changed chessfields 
    }
```

and here I call method

```
Logic.MakeAllMovesForWhites(currentChessfield);
```

I understand what is the problem. And Joel - you are explaining very good ! (y) Thank you.

My first attemp to solve it was (before I ask here):

```
Chessfield abc = new Chessfield();
abc = chessfieldModel;
abc.pieces[indexOfCurrentPosition] = 0;
abc.whites[indexOfCurrentPosition] = true;
abc.pieces[localIndexIterator] = 2;
abc.whites[localIndexIterator] = false;
listOfPossibleMoves.Add(abc);
```

Fail. I tried this in every case (create for every figure and every direction). By the way there are 33 different cases how figure can move in chess, so I had this piece of code above in this 33 places (but sometimes I put different things to tables..). But figure like tower can move left for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 fields if there are not pieces on the left.. and this is problem that I must to create always new instance and I do not know how, because I must to create unique instance, change it a bit, and add to list.. always unique, but in different cases.

Also I have tried your solution Joel, but the problem is that I need to do some changes to original chessfield (4 rows always, but different changes for different figures).
But I tried to create a new instance, add it to list, and then change it while is already on list. Doesn't work and logic is not proper even then.

```
listOfPossibleMoves.Add(new Chessfield() { pieces = chessfieldModel.pieces, blacks = chessfieldModel.blacks, whites = chessfieldModel.whites });
listOfPossibleMoves[listOfPossibleMoves.Count - 1].pieces[indexOfCurrentPosition] = 0;
listOfPossibleMoves[listOfPossibleMoves.Count - 1].whites[indexOfCurrentPosition] = false;
listOfPossibleMoves[listOfPossibleMoves.Count - 1].pieces[localIndexIterator] = 2;
listOfPossibleMoves[listOfPossibleMoves.Count - 1].whites[localIndexIterator] = true;
```

EDIT: So maybe coming back to my first method, but how I can create unique name for objects creating in the same place ? May you recommend some technique or what I can do in this situation ?

Thanks Joel and all :)
Have a nice day (or night) everybody !

Comment: Code would be helpful.

Comment: Rather than change an existing object you need to create a new object based off the first.  You might want to make your class immutable and then expose methods that create new instances that are clones with the changes you want (this would be very similar to how `string` works).

Answer (score 2):

It would really help to see code in the question, but it sounds like you're doing something like this:

```
public class ChessField 
{
   public bool b1;
   public bool b2;
   public int i1;
}

public List<ChessField> Method(ChessField c)
{
    var result = new List<ChessField>();
    for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
       c.i1 = i;
       result.Add(c);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's the problem: you are adding the *same* object to the list. `result[0]` refers to the same object instance as `result[1]` refers to the same object instance as `result[2]` refers to the same object instance as `c`. Changing a property in `c` changes it everywhere else in this code, because they all are variables for the *same* object in memory. If you need the objects to be different, you must do something to create new object instances, like this:

```
public List<ChessField> Method(ChessField c)
{
    var result = new List<ChessField>();
    for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
       result.Add(new ChessField() {b1 = c.b1, b2 = c.b2, i1 = i});
    }
    return result;
}
```

or my preferred style would do this:

```
public IEnumerable<ChessField> Method(ChessField c)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
                    .Select(i => new ChessField() {b1 = c.b1, b2 = c.b2, i1 = i});
}
```